# Can I Recycle Broken Game Cartridges?

Tags: game-boy

I have a Kirby Pinball Gamebody Game Cartridge that apparently no longer works - start it up and just get a grey / white screen. Now that my cartridge is broken, should I just throw it in the trash and be done with it or is there a way I can recycle it or ( maybe ) fix it?

I would **love** to fix it if possible but since I'm not sure it is possible I'd rather recycle it than throw it in the trash ( if possible ).

The reason I believe it is broke is because at some point it had gotten moist ( a few months ago ) I tried to draw it out and such but ever since, whenever I start it up I get to the Nintendo Screen then it goes to a Blue Screen with some waves. The game is:

[Kirby Pinball Land](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirby%27s_Pinball_Land)

Comment: Which do you want to do?  If you want to fix it, we're going to need a ton more information.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I am asking two questions because I don't know *IF* it's fixable and if it's useful to somebody else or recyclable I also don't want to throw it away. I'll add some more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common reason cartridge games screw up like this is that the pins are dirty. Depending on how long it remained moist, possibly corroded, which is likely not as easily fixable as dirt. [This article](http://www.ebay.com/gds/Why-doesnt-my-game-cartridge-work-NES-Genesis-SNES-/10000000003016593/g.html) recommends cleaning the contacts with rubbing alcohol on a Q-tip. If rubbing alcohol is not available, I've read distilled water can also work. As well as several differing opinions on which is better for the longevity of the cartridge. Then drying thoroughly with the other side of the Q-tip and leaving what little remains to evaporate for a few minutes.

If this doesn't work, you might try doing the same to the pin connectors on the system (as some of the grime may have rubbed off of the dirty connectors on the cartridge). As a last resort, depending on if the moisture penetrated into the cartridge, you could try opening it up and repeating the swabbing process on the entire circuit board (both sides).

---

Assuming it is beyond repair, [it *can* be recycled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_waste#Recycling). However E-waste is not typically taken along with more 'traditional' recycling items (papers, plastics, metals). *Properly* disposing E-waste generally involves making a trip to the nearest center that handles such things, so it tends to be best to keep a storage bin somewhere that you can slowly fill over time, rather than making a trip for every single small item.

It is probably a good idea to [Google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=e-waste) what your local options are, and research those options to ensure that the company in question doesn't just have a "[Not in my backyard](http://www.theguardian.com/global-development/2013/dec/14/toxic-ewaste-illegal-dumping-developing-countries)" approach to recycling. Additionally, be aware that the companies involved may charge a fee based either on number of items or weight to have them take your E-waste. The companies around where I live often have (bi)yearly free weekends.

Comment: Thanks for the researched answer. I'll most likely try the first approach and worst comes to worst I *believe* Best Buy has an e-waste drop off.